# Unexpected file found in package directory:

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, github, cli

I am trying to deploy some components from github branch to dev sandbox with VS Code

I am on the branch, where I have a code, and connected to the sandbox.

I tried:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -c -p force-app/main/default
```

as well as:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x ./manifest/STY_0001_package.xml -u releasemanager@companyname.com.qabox -l NoTestRun
sfdx force:source:deploy -c -x ./manifest/package.xml -u releasemanager@companyname.com.qabox -l NoTestRun
```

as well as simple "SFDX:Deploy Source to Org".

I went through all posted messages, fixed metadataTypeInfos.json to add an Audience object.

Placed force-app/main/default/customindex in the .forceignore.

Now I am facing the same error again but for the objects.

Can this somehow to be resolved?

I am in Windows 10 with VS Code 1.55 and sfdx-cli/7.94.3-a4e7c7955b win32-x64 node-v14.15.4

Comment: What's the exact error message you are getting ?

Comment: Have you tried just `sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The results are the same. running force:source:deploy:  Unexpected file found in package directory: C:\GIT_REPOS\SF_PGE_SERVICES_SFDX\force-app\main\default\apexEmailNotifications\apexEmailNotifications.notifications-meta.xml. Also, tried in others salesforce orgs, as well, with the same outcome